# Nearby Messages API permission declaration in manifest?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

I've followed this https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview and have setup the Nearby Messages implementation into one of my apps. I change the payload, depending on certain actions within the app by changing the Message mDeviceInfoMessage to a different DeviceMessage Class.

Also, I'm using:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'

To ensure a seamless experience to the users, I was looking into if there is a way for us to include the Nearby Messages API permissions in the manifest? Since, the app is a first release it would ideal to get the permissions via the Manifest, instead of the permission dialog in the onStart?

Thanks,
Arnab

Comment: i think for the Android M, some of the permission need to be check just in the running time. For more info, please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check).

Comment: While this is true for runtime permissions from Android M. Are there ways to define the Nearby Messages API permissions in the manifest for earlier versions?